# .NET 4.0 dependency property using UIPropertyMetadata not working

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, dependency-properties

I have the following dependency property definition that works perfectly in .NET 3.5:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIdsProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register(
         "SelectedIds",
         typeof(IEnumerable),
         typeof(AddressBookSelector),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(null, UpdateUIText));

    public IEnumerable SelectedIds 
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedIdsProperty); }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(SelectedIdsProperty, value);                 
            }
        }

   static void UpdateUIText(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            (depObj as AddressBookSelector).UpdateRichTextBox();            
        }
```

When I compile the code to run on .NET 4.0, UpdateUIText is no longer called when the value of SelectedIds change. How do I correct this?

Comment: I took the time to compile your code with .NET 4.0 and it seems as if `UpdateUIText()` is correctly called when I modify the value of `SelectedIds` like this: `_selector.SelectedIds = new List<object>()`. Therefore, everything seems to be fine. How do you modify `SelectedIds`?

Comment: SelectedIds is being assigned like this:  SelectedIds = AddrBookEditor.SelectedItems where SelectedItems is an ObservableCollection.  Interesting enough, if I also do SelectedIds = new List<object>, UpdateUIText is called.